# Changing the URL when loading new ajax content

Tags: jquery, html, function

O hai!

So here is the thing: I want to load content in my main div by means of jQuery's beautiful `load()` function when a link in the navigation is clicked. So far so good, this works perfectly. I also want to change the title of the page when a navigation link is clicked to the title attribute of that link. This works as well. But finally I would also want to change the URL of the page! Now I don't really know how this is possible without reloading the whole page.

Here is my current code:
jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav ul li a').click(function() {
        $('nav ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.contentPage').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#sectionContainer').hide().load($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');
        $('title').text($(this).attr('title'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

But how can I change the current URL (that is shown in the address bar and which can be copy-pasted and which redirects to the correct'page') without reloading the whole page?

Another thing I would want is that all pages in the nav can be reached even when JS is disabled. You might say that this is what happening already, right? Well, no, not really. The elements that I load are all simple html files, but lacking any body, html, head. They merely consist of a section; example:

```
<section id="Pages2" class="contentPage">
    <h3>Portfolio</h3>
    <p>
        Vivamus turpis ligula, dignissim vel mollis id, vestibulum quis eros. Donec mi ligula, accumsan sed malesuada in, bibendum sit amet elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam eros quam, iaculis aliquet viverra a, adipiscing nec elit. Nulla facilisi. Quisque tincidunt bibendum eros, et porttitor leo commodo sed. Nullam non tempus nisi. Nulla turpis elit, suscipit id bibendum at, eleifend a lectus. Quisque est sapien, bibendum a pharetra sed, dictum eu neque. Morbi eget ipsum leo. Nam tincidunt fringilla nisi id congue.
    </p>
</section>
<!-- end Page2 -->
```

So, when Javascript is disabled, I will only get to a fully black-on-white, default page lay-out. I don't know how I can make it so that the page that is loaded contains all the css and the menu and footer (so a user gets a normal lay-out when JS is disabled) but that when the page is embeded with `load()` it does not screw the lay-out (and does not contain an extra menu and footer etc.)

Any ideas for this?

Comment: 1. Use a variable for $(this), because it will increase the speed and performance.
2. IDK the answer on how to c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not well supported at the moment by IE, but you can use `history.pushState()`.

[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer, even though a more thorough answer would have been appreciated. ;) The bugger was return false; Here is the final code: http://jsfiddle.net/E4tXh/